# How do airports check incoming goods

Tags: airports, x-ray-machines

How do airports test products or goods that are kept in sale stalls past the point of the security checkpoint? More specifically, if there is a restaurant such as Starbucks that is located near the gates well past security, how does the airport check the products brought in for the Starbucks store? What methods do they use, x-ray or smell etc?

Comment: I assume x-rays, dogs and manual inspections.

Comment: I think it has to be airport specific, larger airports have better equipment compared to smaller ones. But it would be a closed and monitored process.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to travel.

Comment: Originally had to on aviation.se and they told me to put it here so I did, no longer care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large airports receiving and distribution centers (sometimes called concession logistics centers) are built to provide a consolidated location for receiving, screening, and distribution of all goods destined for the concession areas (for both pre-security and postsecurity locations). For example, San Diego has a near-18000 foot center where all goods are initially delivered.

The checks include visual inspection, and x-raying.

Smaller airports require authorized personnel to take goods through the regular screening process. This is a much slower (and less cost effective) approach. Delivery times are often strictly controlled to ensure security resources aren't used for concession delivery when the airport is busy with passengers.

The advantage of the large centers is that they provide centralized control and optimization of resources.